# Measurabilty of supremum

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Consider a measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$.

Is the supremum of an uncountable family of Borel measurable functions of the type $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ a Borel measurable function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [supremum of uncountable families of Borel measurable functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452766/supremum-of-uncountable-families-of-borel-measurable-functions)

Answer (score 2):

Let $E$ be any nonmeasurable set and $f_t(x)=1$ if $t=x$ and $0$ otherwise. Then $sup \{f_t(x):t \in E\}=\chi_E$ which is not measurable but each $f_t$ is measurable.

Comment: What about we consider the lattice supremum?